# How To Format Loop to Read Text Files Then Create And Populate DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, text-files

I'm stumped, I cannot seem to figure out why this loop only produces the following in the datagridview: 
[image]

The code I am using is:

```
Private Sub ReadTextFiles()
    Dim textline As String
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Columns.Add("Date & Time")
    dt.Columns.Add("Name")
    dt.Columns.Add("tpnb")
    dt.Columns.Add("Description")
    dt.Columns.Add("id")
    dt.Columns.Add("Department")
    dt.Columns.Add("Price")

    Dim fileentries As String() = Directory.GetFiles("D:\Comp Sci\ASC_BCKUP_260119\ASC_w-Login\bin\Debug\Orders")
    For Each entry In fileentries
        Dim linecount As Integer = File.ReadAllLines(entry).Length
        Dim rowcount As Integer = linecount / 7
        Using reader As New StreamReader(entry)
            For rowcount = 0 To rowcount - 1
                dt.Rows.Add()
                For col = 0 To 6
                    textline = reader.ReadLine()
                    TextBox1.Text += textline
                    dt.Rows(rowcount)(col) = textline
                Next
            Next
        End Using
    Next
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    'DataGridView1.Columns("Price").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "£00:00"
End Sub
```

I've added `textbox1` to see what it contains and it contains all of the data, however the datagridview doesn't and I can't see why. The datagridview only appends 3 product's information to it, why I'm not sure why it does.

The directory contains 3 text files with 35 lines in total, so a total of 5 products should be visible in the datagridview.

To clear things up:
The loop here should be iterating over the datagridview and writing the relevant information into each cell. For each product there is 7 bits of information, as can be seen in the image of the datagridview.

I have tried using `dim dr = dt.NewRow()` and `dt.rows.add(dr)` however the datagridview is now blank, containing only the column headers.

Here is an image of **one** of the text files.

[image: Image of text file and how the information is stored.]

Any help is greatly appreciated to relieve me from the frustration.

Comment: You are re-setting `rowcount` after reach file so you are overwriting rows. I suggest you use `dt.NewRow()` to get a new row then `Add()` the row to the `DataTable` so you don't even need to deal with row indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for any number of files with any number of products in each file as long as the number of lines per products remains at 7.

```
Private Sub ReadTextFiles()
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Columns.Add("Date & Time")
    dt.Columns.Add("Name")
    dt.Columns.Add("tpnb")
    dt.Columns.Add("Description")
    dt.Columns.Add("id")
    dt.Columns.Add("Department")
    dt.Columns.Add("Price")
    '3 files
    '7 fields
    '35 lines total
    '5 products
    Dim fileentries As String() = Directory.GetFiles("TestFiles")
    Dim lstLines As New List(Of String)
    For Each entry In fileentries
        lstLines.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(entry))
    Next
    'Now we have all the data lines in a list
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim OuterLoopIterations As Integer = CInt(lstLines.Count / 7)
    For iterations = 0 To OuterLoopIterations - 1
        Dim row = dt.NewRow
        For col = 0 To 6
            row(col) = lstLines(i)
            i += 1
        Next
        dt.Rows.Add(row)
    Next
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you kindly Mary. I guess like @JohnG said I really was over-complicating things.

Answer (score 0):

From just looking at your code - Your dt.Rows.Add() is what adds rows to your datatable. It is only adding the 3 rows available at the point you call it. 
Put a break point above it and see whats available when its adding to the datatable. You might have to move that statement. 
Also, you can check which file its adding from - the 3 items displayed are they from different files or the same? That will tell you at what point your adding is faulty.

Comment: Hmm, it seems as though `rowcount = 0` and the file the file it's reading from the contents are not being written to the datagridview. However, the 3 products that can be seen in the datagridview are all from the same file.

Comment: I think I've figured out the issue, the datagridview gets overwritten each time the loop is iterated. However, I'm not entirely sure how to go about this, hmm.

Comment: Move  dt.Rows.Add() into the last loop - i think that should do it - i havent tested it cos i dont have the text file.

Comment: If you share the content of the text file that would help.